# Removing hyphens from a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to take the hyphen or dash out of a birthdate.
01/01/01
01-01-01
I need to combine the birthdate with other fields and it can't have the seperator in it.

I am sure there is a better way. I can get the month and year out, using left & right however I can't figure out how to get the middle out. Below is what I have so far and I know that I can combine them using "&"...if someone can help me with the middle or give me a better equation I would appreciate it.

LEFT(A1,2)

RIGHT(A1,2)

Solution:

=LEFT(F2,2)&MID(F2,4,2)&RIGHT(F2,4)

Comment: Is this actually an Excel String of a Date-formatted cell?

Comment: No, the date is not part of the Excel string. I have however tried to eliminate the hyphens using multiple strings. I have tried to remove all of the formatting and even change the format to mmddyyyy using the custom option, however it will not remove the hyphens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is a string, (not formated as a date) then you can use

```
MID(A1,4,2)
```

otherwise i just use the MONTH(A1) DAY(A1) YEAR(A1) functions

Comment: Thank you AI W that is exactly what I needed. Where does the 4 come from? That is what I missing, so I am just curious.

Comment: Mid
In Excel, the Mid function extracts a substring from a string (starting at any position). The syntax for the Mid function is: Mid( text, start_position, number_of_characters ) text is the string that you wish to extract from. start_position indicates the position in the string that you will begin extracting from. The first position in the string is 1. number_of_characters indicates the number of characters that you wish to extract.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what an excel formula is so this answer might be irrelevant...

VBA has a `Mid` function that would do what you want I believe. This page has good explanations for that and the other similar functions: http://www.vbtutor.net/VBA/vba9.htm

Answer (score 0):

Change the number format of the date to something line "mmddyy". To combine it with other text in another cell, use a formula like:

```
="The date is "&TEXT(A1,"mmddyy")
```

where the date is in cell A1.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a Find and Replace to replace the "-" with nothing.

Ctrl + H will bring up the Replace dialog box.